# How many different combinations with 16 black and white pieces are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 16 black pieces and 16 white pieces and a board with 32 spots to put them. How many different combinations are there for the board?
I tries using faculties but they only work with distinct pieces.

Comment: The answer is $\binom{32}{16}$ (number of sets with 16 elements among 32)

Comment: It's equivalent to choose $16$ positions on the $32$-spots (for the black pieces by example). So the answer would be $C^{32}_{16}$.

Another way to look at this is that you have $32!$ way to arrange $32$ distinct pieces. Since you're free to permute the $16$ black pieces, this number should be reduced by $16!$, and identically for the white pieces. So the result is $32!/(16!.16!)$, which is $C^{32}_{16}$.

Comment: whats that dot between the 16!s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose all the 32 pieces are different. 32! ways to put them. Then divide by $16!$ for the number of combinations inside the white ones. Do the same for the black ones. Then we get $\frac{32!}{(16!)^2}$.